# Execute commands on user login/logout

Tags: linux, bash, user-management

When I log into my linux user through ssh, the user should automatically execute a set of commands. Same thing when I log out of my user. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your user's shell is bash, put commands to be executed in the files `~/.bash_login` and `~/.bash_logout`.  The former is executed at login time (modulo certain configuration choices), and the latter at logout.  There are analogues for most other shells.

Comment: What if I'm logging into /bin/false and my user doesen't have a home directory?

Comment: If your user has no shell, (s)he can't log in, so the question doesn't apply.